# Why is React not treating my array properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, console.log

When I render this React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

// import RenderLineChart from "../recharts/rechart.component";
import axios from "axios";

import "./chart-item.styles.scss";

const ChartItem = ({ apiUrl }) => {
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);

    //function that pulls data from APIs
    const loadChartData = useCallback(() => {
        axios.get(apiUrl).then((response) => {
            setChartData(response.data);
        });
    }, [apiUrl]);

    //runs initial pull from API
    useEffect(() => {
        loadChartData();
    }, [loadChartData]);

    console.log("Raw Data: ");
    console.log(chartData);

    console.log("Array: ");
    console.log(chartData.historical);

    // console.log("Array Element: ");
    // console.log(chartData.historical[0]);

    return <div className="chart"></div>;
};

export default ChartItem;
```

The console output is such:
[image]

When I uncomment that third console.log statement and save the component file *without* refreshing localhost, the output is:

[image]

But when I actually refresh the localhost tab, the output is such:

[image]

As if it is no longer being treated as an array. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: `chartData` is originally an empty array: `useState([]);`, until data is loaded, which doesn't have `.historical`, and you are trying to read `.historical[0]`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in the snippet you posted.

1. You're declaring `chartData` as an array, but then you're updating it with an object (inside the `loadChartData` function)
2. When page loads the `console.log` is executed before the `loadChartData` function has completed the request, so at the first render `chartData = [] and chartData[0] = undefined`, but if you try to get `chartData.historical[0]` it throws you an error because it is defined as an array.

So, how can you fix this? The answer is pretty straightforward, first of all you have to use a consistend data-type for your state, if it's an array when declared, then when you update it, pass an array, if not you'll always have this kind of problems. This should fit your needs. If you want to log `chartData` everytime it upates you just need to write a new `useEffect` with the `console.log` inside and `chartData` as "dependency"

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({ historical: [] })

// declare you api call
const apiCall = useCallback(() => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    setChartData(response.data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}, [setChartData])

useEffect(() => {
  apiCall()
}, [apiCall])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Raw Data: ");
  console.log(chartData);

  console.log("Array: ");
  console.log(chartData.historical);

  console.log("Array Element: ");
  console.log(chartData.historical[0]);
}, [chartData])

// do you stuff with jsx
```

I suggest you to take a look at [Hooks Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)

Hope this helps ✌️